# Ubuntu 19.04 won't boot with Nvidia proprietary drivers (418)

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I upgraded today from 18.04 to 19.04, and after the installation my system refused to boot (it was stuck on that black screen with the green [ok] lines). I then installed it without the third party extras, and it booted normally, but as soon as I installed the most recent nvidia drivers from the software & updates menu, it refused to boot again.
Right now i'm using the nouveau drivers without problems, but I still want to update them to be able to play my games. How can I solve this problem?
My GPU is a GTX 1060 6GB.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Another user just reported `418` was broken for suspend/resume and using `396` fixed it.

Comment: There's no 396, only 390, and it still didn't work for me :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to this [link](https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-disable-wayland-and-enable-xorg-display-server-on-ubuntu-18-04-bionic-beaver-linux), in order to have the Nvidia drivers working, you have to disable wayland.
To do so:

- **Open custom.conf to edit it:**

  Choose your preferred text editor (for example gedit or nano) then run:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/gdm3/custom.conf
  ```
- **Edit the file:**

  You will find the line `#WaylandEnable=false` commented, to un-comment it, remove the `'#'` in the beginning of the line.
- **Apply the changes:**

  To have these changes applied, save the edits, then reboot your computer.

Answer (score 3):

GDM3 starting with wayland!

Disable on

```
/etc/gdm3/custom.conf
```

uncomment

```
#WaylandEnable=false
```

to

```
WaylandEnable=false
```

Answer (score 1):

I just went through this.

```
sudo apt-get purge nvidia*
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:graphics-drivers
sudo apt-get update
```

Open Software & Updates > Other Software
Select all ppa.lunchpad.net/graphic-drivers, especially (Source Code)

```
sudo apt-get update
ubuntu-drivers devices
ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

Its going to ask to create a secure boot password (remember this).
Go through the prompts to install everything and reboot.

When the blue screen pops up to manage keys hit enter.
Follow the prompts to add the key and enter the password.
If the key gets added and everything goes through it will work.  I had to build the driver from source for it to work.

[gtx1080](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HQP6.png)

Answer (score 1):

To bring up the grub menu during boot

`sudo vi /etc/default/grub`
Change the time from 0 to 10 : GRUB-TIMEOUT=10

To fix stucking at ubuntu logo during boot or  To fix stucking at the black screen with green OK lines @ line: `snd_hda_intel`.

1) `vi /etc/gdm3/custom.conf`
2) uncomment

`# WaylandEnable=false`
to

`WaylandEnable=false`

If still stuck at logo during boot

1) Enter grub menu

2) press <kbd>E</kbd> to edit the grub

3)Change the line: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset`

4) reboot to login

To have a permanent solution :

5)  `sudo vi /etc/default/grub`

6)Change the line:`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"`

to: `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset`

7) `sudo update-grub2`

(I experienced screen lag in ubuntu on using nomodeset)
step 6 can also be done in Recovery mode from the grub menu itself

Answer (score 0):

Open terminal and edit your grub file.

```
sudo vi /etc/default/grub
```

or:

```
sudo nano /etc/default/grub
```

Change the line:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
```

to:

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash nomodeset"
```

And finally save and reboot.

Comment: Didn't Work :( the screen still freezes at the same place

Comment: Changes to `grub` only take effect after running `sudo update-grub`.