# nvidia driver hangs gdm on boot

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, xorg, 19.04

both recommended drivers hangs gdm on boot, specifics are for video card are as follows;

```
== /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:02.0/0000:01:00.0 ==
modalias : pci:v000010DEd00001082sv000010DEsd00000873bc03sc00i00
vendor   : NVIDIA Corporation
model    : GF110 [GeForce GTX 560 Ti OEM]
driver   : nvidia-driver-390 - distro non-free recommended
driver   : nvidia-340 - distro non-free
driver   : xserver-xorg-video-nouveau - distro free builtin
```

Any ideas

Answer (score 1):

This [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135869/ubuntu-19-04-wont-boot-with-nvidia-proprietary-drivers-418/1135914) explains how to disable wayland on boot for Ubuntu 19.04.
It only requires the wayland driver disabled. The nomodeset does not have to be applied.

Once editing is complete, you can install the Nvidia driver from a terminal as follows

```
sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall
```

or

```
sudo apt install nvidia-driver-(driver number to install)
```

Answer (score 0):

if this link works for you, pls paste that solution in here.
[amdgpu driver refuses to load on 19.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1135590/amdgpu-driver-refuses-to-load-on-19-04)
not that I made an error.... it's /boot/grub/grub.cfg for the timeout setting.